# Get content from helper (Draggable) in event update from sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, helper

How i can get the content declared in draggable "helper" in event "update" from sortable from object?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      update: function(event, ui){
          ??????
      }
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: function(e){
        return $('<div>sample</div>');
    },
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var draggableHelper = $(this).data('helper');//setted in draggable start handler
        }
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: function (e) {
            return $('<div>sample</div>');
        },
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $($(this).draggable('option','connectToSortable')).data('helper', ui.helper);
        }
    });
    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Is possible change $("#sortable") for a dynamic value in start?

Comment: Explain what you call dynamic value?

Comment: $ (this). <something> $ hi (ui) where it was not necessary for me to retype the name of the sortable I already stated.

Comment: You could just use $('.ui-sortable') or better $(this).draggable('option','connectToSortable') see updated post